# How to understand this sheaf $\mathscr{O}_C(d-3)(-\Delta)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C\to C'$ be the normalization of some nodal plane curve $C'\subseteq\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\Delta$ be the divisor of preimage of nodes. Then $\mathscr{O}_C(d-3)$ is the twisted structure sheaf. Now, we tensor $\mathscr{O}(-\Delta)$, the sheaf associated to the divisor. The definition is clear. But I am interested in its intepretation.

Say the node of the curves are $p_1,...,p_n$. If we take the global section $\Gamma(C,\mathscr{O}_C(d-3)(-\Delta))$, will the space corresponds to the space of curves of degree $d-3$ passing these nodes?